# Having trouble PUTting profile variables in Watson Dialog service

Tags: json, ibm-watson

I think this is actually two (related) problems. If I try to set profile variables in the **Watson Dialog API** via *Postman*, I don't get any errors (200 return code) but the variables don't get set. This is the data I'm sending:

> ```
> {
>   "client_id": 152008,
>   "name_values":[ 
>     {
>       "name": "second",
>       "value": "2"
>     }]
> }
> ```

and this is the answer I get:

```
{
  "client_id": 152008,
  "name_values": []
}
```

Doing a GET confirms that the variables were not set.

If I try to do it via *dialog.updateProfile()* in the *watson-developer-cloud* package using the same JSON, I get

```
Error: Missing required parameters: name_values
```

instead.

Has anyone successfully set Watson Dialog profile variables? How did you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dialog profile variable you wish to manipulate via the API needs to already exist in the Dialog XML file. You can not create a new Dialog profile variable via the API.

Comment: That was the first problem.  Didn't realize that the variable names had to be pre-created.  But the 2nd problem still stands, still can't do it via the watson-developer-cloud package.

Comment: Seems like I should have received an error message for trying to set a variable that wasn't there.  Hmmm.

Comment: I've fixed the issue in the npm module, it will be available in the next release. probably tomorrow